# Expected status code 200 but received 500

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, continuous-integration, gitlab

That's the code for my unit test.
It's working fine on local machine but when I push it to gitLab, I get

```
Expected status code 200 but received 500.
Failed asserting that false is true.
```

I've other similar tests too, but those tests are working fine.
The error I'm getting is against `edit` url.

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit;

use App\Models\ACL\Permission;
use App\Models\ACL\Role;
use App\Models\Benefit\EmployeeDependent;
use App\Models\Employee\Employee;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Tests\TestCase;

class EmployeeDependentPolicyTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;

    public function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->seed();
    }

    /**
     * Full Admin
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function createUserWithAdminRole()
    {
        $admin = factory(Employee::class)->create();
        $admin->assignRole('admin');
        return $admin;
    }

    /**
     *
     * A user with edit first and last name of dependents can create new dependents
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function createEmployeeRoleWithCreateDependentPermissions()
    {
        $employeeRole = factory(Role::class)->create(['type' => 'employee']);
        DB::table('role_permission_has_access_levels')->insert([
            ['role_id' => $employeeRole->id, 'permission_id' => (Permission::where('name', 'edit employeedependent first_name')->pluck('id')->first()), 'access_level_id' => 0],
            ['role_id' => $employeeRole->id, 'permission_id' => (Permission::where('name', 'edit employeedependent last_name')->pluck('id')->first()), 'access_level_id' => 0],
            ['role_id' => $employeeRole->id, 'permission_id' => (Permission::where('name', 'view employeedependent middlename')->pluck('id')->first()), 'access_level_id' => 0],
                ]);

        return $employeeRole;
    }

    /**
     * A user with any of the edit dependent permissions can edit dependent
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function createEmployeeRoleWithEditDependentPermissions()
    {
        $employeeRole = factory(Role::class)->create(['type' => 'employee']);
        DB::table('role_permission_has_access_levels')->insert([
            ['role_id' => $employeeRole->id, 'permission_id' => (Permission::where('name', 'view employeedependent first_name')->pluck('id')->first()), 'access_level_id' => 0],
            ['role_id' => $employeeRole->id, 'permission_id' => (Permission::where('name', 'edit employeedependent last_name')->pluck('id')->first()), 'access_level_id' => 0],
            ['role_id' => $employeeRole->id, 'permission_id' => (Permission::where('name', 'view employeedependent middlename')->pluck('id')->first()), 'access_level_id' => 0],
        ]);

        return $employeeRole;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function createEmployeeWithCreatePermissions()
    {
        $employee['employee'] = factory(Employee::class)->create();
        $employee['role'] = $this->createEmployeeRoleWithCreateDependentPermissions();
        $employee['employee']->assignRole($employee['role']->name);
        $employee['dependent']=$this->createEmployeeDependents($employee['employee']->id);
        return $employee;
    }
    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function createEmployeeWithEditPermissions()
    {
        $employee['employee'] = factory(Employee::class)->create();
        $employee['role'] = $this->createEmployeeRoleWithEditDependentPermissions();
        $employee['employee']->assignRole($employee['role']->name);
        $employee['dependent']=$this->createEmployeeDependents($employee['employee']->id);
        return $employee;
    }

    /**
     *  Admin can view all employees' dependents
     */
    public function test_admin_can_view_dependents_of_all_employees()
    {
        $admin = $this->createUserWithAdminRole();
        $employee1 = $this->createEmployeeWithCreatePermissions();
        $response = $this->actingAs($admin)
            ->get('/en/employees/' . $employee1['employee']->id.'/dependents');
        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }

    /**
     * Admin can access create/edit dependents page for all Employees
     */
    public function test_admin_can_create_and_edit_dependents_for_all_employees()
    {
        $admin = $this->createUserWithAdminRole();
        $employee1 = $this->createEmployeeWithCreatePermissions();
        $response = $this->actingAs($admin)
            ->get('/en/employees/' . $employee1['employee']->id.'/dependents/create');
        $response->assertStatus(200);
        $response = $this->actingAs($admin)
            ->get('/en/employees/' . $employee1['employee']->id.'/dependents/'.$employee1['dependent']->id.'/edit');
        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }

    /**
     * @param $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function createEmployeeDependents($id)
    {
        return factory(EmployeeDependent::class)->create(['emp_id'=> $id]);
    }

    /**
     *  Employee can view his dependents
     */
    public function test_employee_can_view_his_dependents()
    {
        $employee = $this->createEmployeeWithCreatePermissions();
        $response = $this->actingAs($employee['employee'])
            ->get('/en/employees/' . $employee['employee']->id.'/dependents');
        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }
    /**
     *  Employee who can create his dependents can also edit
     */
    public function test_employee_can_create_and_edit_his_dependents()
    {
        $employee = $this->createEmployeeWithCreatePermissions();
        $response = $this->actingAs($employee['employee'])
            ->get('/en/employees/' . $employee['employee']->id.'/dependents/create');
        $response->assertStatus(200);
        $response = $this->actingAs($employee['employee'])
            ->get('/en/employees/' . $employee['employee']->id.'/dependents/'.$employee['dependent']->id.'/edit');
        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }

    /**
     *  Employee who can no permission to edit first or last name cannot create his dependents but only edit them
     */
    public function test_employee_can_edit_his_dependents_but_not_create()
    {
        $employee = $this->createEmployeeWithEditPermissions();
        $response = $this->actingAs($employee['employee'])
            ->get('/en/employees/' . $employee['employee']->id.'/dependents/create');
        $response->assertStatus(403);
        $response = $this->actingAs($employee['employee'])
            ->get('/en/employees/' . $employee['employee']->id.'/dependents/'.$employee['dependent']->id.'/edit');
        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }
}
```

That's my error log:

```
continuous-integration — test
00:23


latest: Pulling from jakzal/phpqa
Digest: sha256:9638cd6c39a865c5f80ae29d02348cce3918a6709d8f8cee4d9cb054860b81b1
Status: Image is up to date for jakzal/phpqa:latest
+ vendor/bin/phpunit --no-coverage --colors=never
PHPUnit 7.5.17 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

R.R...RR....R............F.FF.............                        42 / 42 (100%)

Time: 21.39 seconds, Memory: 44.00 MB

There were 3 failures:

1) Tests\Unit\EmployeeDependentPolicyTest::test_admin_can_create_and_edit_dependents_for_all_employees
Expected status code 200 but received 500.
Failed asserting that false is true.

/drone/src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestResponse.php:151
/drone/src/tests/Unit/EmployeeDependentPolicyTest.php:114

2) Tests\Unit\EmployeeDependentPolicyTest::test_employee_can_create_and_edit_his_dependents
Expected status code 200 but received 500.
Failed asserting that false is true.

/drone/src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestResponse.php:151
/drone/src/tests/Unit/EmployeeDependentPolicyTest.php:147

3) Tests\Unit\EmployeeDependentPolicyTest::test_employee_can_edit_his_dependents_but_not_create
Expected status code 200 but received 500.
Failed asserting that false is true.

/drone/src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestResponse.php:151
/drone/src/tests/Unit/EmployeeDependentPolicyTest.php:161

--

There were 5 risky tests:

1) Tests\Feature\EditMangerTest::test_admin_can_edit_manager
This test did not perform any assertions

/drone/src/tests/Feature/EditMangerTest.php:14

2) Tests\Feature\createRoleTest::test_user_can_create_role
This test did not perform any assertions

/drone/src/tests/Feature/createRoleTest.php:11

3) Tests\Unit\Approval\restoreStandardApprovalTest::testStandardApprovalHaveDefaultFields
This test did not perform any assertions

/drone/src/tests/Unit/Approval/restoreStandardApprovalTest.php:14

4) Tests\Unit\Approval\restoreStandardApprovalTest::testRestoreStandardApproval
This test did not perform any assertions

/drone/src/tests/Unit/Approval/restoreStandardApprovalTest.php:20

5) Tests\Unit\DefaultApprovalsTest::testDefaultApprovalsCount
This test did not perform any assertions

/drone/src/tests/Unit/DefaultApprovalsTest.php:22

FAILURES!
Tests: 42, Assertions: 100, Failures: 3, Risky: 5.
DocumentationPluginsSupport
GitHubTwitterDiscourseGitter
```

Comment: You will need to find the concrete errors that is thrown, here it is basically just that the "webserver" crashed, we have no idea how to fix that. Logs would help. Most likely the error is related to env's not being the same or not running the same versions on dev vs ci

Comment: I don't know where I can find the log on CI.

Comment: I've setup a different environment for testing. For dev,  I'm using MySql and for testing I'm using sqlite.

Comment: Add this to your test for debugging and finding what's causing the error 500: `$this->withoutExceptionHandling();`

Comment: @ZoeChan still need the errors.

Comment: @LobsterBaz Thanks.
I didn't give it much thought before posting it. I should have checked the log first. There was some issue with one of my views name.

Comment: Plus, how can I make my local system to show the same error as of the CI? I mean, with my testing, I've found that my local system is skipping my other errors as well.